# How to increase the resolution of an image in python- a possible solution?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I had an interesting idea to increase the resolution of an image by copying every individual pixel 9 times in a grid. So, I went ahead and implemented it in python using the Pillow library.

The issue here is that the image is not sharper or of high resolution than the earlier one. It still looks like the zoomed-in version of the previous image. Please take a gander for yourself.

***1. The new image, generated by the program:-*** 
[image]

***2. The older image, zoomed-in appropriately to match the size of the previous image:-***[image]

I want to know why does it not work as intended? why the image is not sharper? For what it's worth, I have tried to zoom out the new image to the size of the original image, but it's not sharper at all. It looks the same.

My program works as intended but I am still reproducing it here for the sake of completeness. It makes the new image 9 times in size and 3 times wider and 3 times the original height.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

factor = 3

che = Image.open('../dog.jpg')
che.show()
px = che.load()
width, height = che.size


img = Image.new('RGB', (width*factor, height*factor), 'Black')
# img.show()
pixels = img.load()
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        pixels[factor*i, factor*j] = px[i, j]
        pixels[factor*i+1, factor*j] = px[i, j]
        pixels[factor*i+2, factor*j] = px[i, j]

        pixels[factor*i, factor*j+1] = px[i, j]
        pixels[factor*i+1, factor*j+1] = px[i, j]
        pixels[factor*i+2, factor*j+1] = px[i, j]

        pixels[factor*i, factor*j+2] = px[i, j]
        pixels[factor*i+1, factor*j+2] = px[i, j]
        pixels[factor*i+2, factor*j+2] = px[i, j]

# img.show()
img.save('../dog2.jpg')
```

Comment: The image can not be sharper than it was when enlarged it this way—if fact there's no way to do that. There's an image-processing technique called "resampling" that can produce sharper-looking results however.

Comment: See wikipedia article on [image resampling/scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling).

Comment: I'm afraid it's a fundamental law of nature that you can't increase the information content of an image by guessing the bits that aren't there...